# Dell XPS 15 9570 Thermal Shutdown while Gaming

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, steam, xps

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 to the internal drive of my Dell XPS 15 9570.

I'm running kernel 5.4.0-29-generic and the latest nvidia drivers. I recently upgraded the BIOS to 1.15.0.

I'm seeing thermal shutdowns whenever I try to play Steam games at high resolutions. I never saw this when using Windows 10. I've seen a few references to this online but I'm not sure if it's being caused by the BIOS, the Kernel or the graphics drivers. Any ideas what I should do?

[Dell Support Discussion](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9570-Overheating-GPU/td-p/7418784/page/2)

Comment: The Dell XPS 9570 has a very highly overpowered CPU and GPU setting at the hardware/firmware level.  I've fixed it with minor undervolting and minor tweaks with thermal pads on the MOSFETS as per this guide: https://www.ultrabookreview.com/14875-fix-throttling-xps-15/  You may want to look into the thermal pad solution.  This will not void the warranty on the machine AND turns the aluminum bottom into something of a heatsink, wicking away heat from the overly sensitive MOSFETs.  If that alone doesn't work, you should undervolt slightly (and I can provide details in an answer)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm slightly nervous about opening the case but that guide looks good. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: You will need special screwdrivers but in this case you simply just need to open the case and put cut thermal pads down like that part of the guide shows.  dont do anything else except the thermal pads.  That will probably help a bunch.

Comment: So I tried disabling turbo boost in the BIOS, and I put a cooling fan base under the machine. I can now get more than an hour of high resolution gaming before the thermal shutdown occurs. I would be interested to know how to undervolt the machine and I will order some thermal pads anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler solution than heatsinks or undervolting.  TLP is what I'm using.

I have a somewhat similar Dell as you but it has a 10th-gen CPU.  I haven't had any thermal shutdowns but I don't game (just work).  When I first got it, I noticed that if I load it down then it would get really hot, really quickly.

It might not be the same on your 9th-gen CPU but on this one I noticed that the CPU advertises 3.9Ghz but it actually only supports that for 1 core and for a limited time.  It's for single core bursts but Linux was basically trying to run all cores at 3.9Ghz when I loaded it down making it super hot.  The real stable max speed for mine is 3.5Ghz.

So I just used TLP to throttle it down to 3.5.  It would still get a little hotter than I wanted when loaded down like that though so I shaved 5% off to make it 3.325Ghz and now I can run it fully loaded down for as long as I need to and it doesn't get overly hot.  :)

Comment: Thanks. I got cold feet about opening up the case. I've tried dialing down the CPU with TLP and so far it seems to have done the trick. The machine still gets really warm but no more thermal shutdowns so far at least.